# retrieve data from custom delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Its my first time trying to create a custom delegate. I've created a small test to check basic functionally.

basically the `shareRoutine` method in my delegate is called but the return value on the `NSLog` valiable is `NULL` thus implying that  my `- (NSString*) shareRoutineDel` is not being called or retrieved properly.

Could anyone point out why this is not working?

I've included `<shareDelegate>` in the .h file of this `UIViewController`, but havent done more than that and my delegate methods are called in another class via.

```
- (IBAction)share:(UIButton *)sender {
    _share = [[share alloc]init];
    [_share shareRoutine];
}
- (NSString*) shareRoutineDel {
    NSString* a= @"test";
    return a;
}
```

**my delegate class**

```
.h
 @class share;
    @protocol shareDelegate

    @optional
    -(NSString*) shareRoutineDel;
    @end

    @interface share : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<shareDelegate> delegate;
    - (void) shareRoutine;
    @end
```

.m

```
#import "share.h"

@implementation share
@synthesize delegate;

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) shareRoutine {
    NSString * response = [[self delegate] shareRoutineDel];
    NSLog(@"check: %@",response);
}
@end
```

Comment: Where are you setting anything as the delegate?

Comment: I am not setting anything as a delegate anywhere. I've tried doing it in the `init` of `share` but the way i was doing it was wrong and didnt compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a delegate you can't ask it for anything, so you'll always have null.

Try setting the delegate just after you create the test instance:

```
_share = [[share alloc]init];
_share.delegate = self;
[_share shareRoutine];
```

In your question you say "and my delegate methods are called in another class via..." which may mean the above isn't correct, but it's hard to tell. Just get it working with 2 classes until you understand how it works.